# Write the following as a product of disjoint cycles: (10359)^3(261847)^3

Tags: group-theory

I know how to do basic permutations but I get stuck on ones like these with exponents not sure how to start?

Comment: Uhh... what are the elements? $0,1,2\dots9$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes sorry, forgot to mention 10 elements

Answer (score 0):

Cubing a cycle results in jumping three places within the cycle.  So $(10359)^3=(15093)$.  The other one is $(261847)^3=(28)(64)(17)$.

Thus we get $(15093)(28)(64)(17)=(750931)(28)(64)$.

Answer (score 0):

For a cycle, raising it to a power $n$ means applying it $n$ times. Thus we see
$$(10359)^3=(15093)$$
$$(261847)^3=(28)(64)(17)$$
Assuming we apply permutations left-to-right, we get the decomposition of the given permutation as
$$(150937)(28)(64)$$